# List names of required fields in Django Rest Framework serializer (and ignore parent fields)

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

What I'm trying to do is get a list of all the fields in a serializer which:

- Do **not** contain `required=False` as a parameter.
- Do **not** come from the parent serializer.

For example, if I have serializers like:

```
class ParentSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    parent_field = serializers.IntegerField

class ChildSerializer(ParentSerializer):
    child_field_required = serializers.IntegerField
    child_field_not_required = serializers.IntegerField(required=False)
```

I'd like the resulting output to be:

```
['child_field_required']
```

I've figured out I can get an ordered list of the declared fields like:

```
self.get_serializer().get_fields()
>> OrderedDict([
       ('parent_field', IntegerField()),
       ('child_field_required', IntegerField()),
       ('child_field_not_required', IntegerField(required=False)),
])
```

But I haven't been able to move past this step.

Comment: Have you tried this? This allows you to specify which fields you want when you call the serializer. Or do you only need the fields with required=False? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#dynamically-modifying-fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're inhering from `serializers.Serializer`, all fields must be declared explicitly on the class body (unlike `serializers.ModelSerializer` which traverses to the model layer to generate fields automatically). In that case, you can do:

```
parent_field_names = {
    name
    for base in type(instance).__bases__
    if hasattr(base, '_declared_fields')
    for name in base._declared_fields
}
desired_fields = [
    (name, field)
    for name, field in instance.get_fields().items()
    if name not in parent_field_names and
    field._kwargs.get('required', None) is not False
]
```

Assuming `instance` is a `serializers.Serializer` instance. `parent_field_names` refers to a set for O(1) lookups.

The above depends on a couple of **implementation details**:

- The metaclass of `serializers.Serializer` -- `serializers.SerializerMetaclass` assigns the declared fields as class attribute `_declared_fields` dict
- Whole constructing (`__new__`), the `serializers.Field` class preserves the initially passed keyword arguments as the `_kwargs` attribute on the instance to the newly created field instance

---

**Notes:**

- If you want to make this applicable to `serializers.ModelSerializer`'s model fields traversal as well i.e. for non-declared fields or fields overridden in `Meta`, you need to check for `get_fields` of each and then get only the fields that are defined in the current serializer
- [`serializers.SerializerMetaclass` `pop`s off the fields from class attributes while creating the `_declared_fields` attribute](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/8001087e9e335140b8063a23916d9c05b615acd4/rest_framework/serializers.py#L296), so you can't access the fields from class. Otherwise, we could use the attribute check on the base classes to see if any field is defined there, which would result in a shorter code.

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a solution, but I feel like there is a more elegant one out there...

```
instance = ChildSerializer()

serializer_fields = instance.get_fields()
parent_serializer_fields = instance.__class__.__bases__[0]().get_fields()
child_fields = {k: serializer_fields[k] for k in set(serializer_fields) - set(parent_serializer_fields)}
required_fields = [k for k, v in child_fields.items() if v.required]
```